# Show that $L:= [ { (x,y,z) \in R^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 −2xy−2yz + 2xz = 0}] $ is a sub vector space

Tags: proof-verification

Show that $L:= [{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 −2xy−2yz + 2xz =0 }] $ is a sub vector space of $R^3$

Proof:
1) show it is not empty (0,0,0) is inside thus not empty.
2) Scalar multiplication with $\lambda \in K$ multiplied $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in L$ is closed. thus the product is also $\in L$

Addition is however not so clear.
It seems to me I cannot proof the addition part. When I take two elements of $L$ add them at try to show that the sum is also in $L$ I reach a dead end.

Could someone please prove it?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2+y^2+z^2-2xy-2yz+2xz=0$?

Comment: I already edited it, yes  that was what I meant. the equation must be fulfilled for the elements of $L$ exmples are $(0,0,0), (1,2,1) , (2,2,0) $

Comment: What happens if you try brute force?  If $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ both satisfy the relation, just test $(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,z_1+z_2)$.

Comment: if such is tried with (x1,x2,x3) and (y1,y2,y3) then you reach the following 0+0 + x1(y1-y2+y3) + x2(-y1+y2-y3) + x3(-y1-y2+y3)  = 0

Comment: Well, you should either get $0$ or you should reach a point where a good choice of coordinates gets you a counterexample.

Comment: Not with brute force as I mentioned the end result is not clear. Bjorns answer and reform of the equation is the right way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition
$$x^2+y^2+z^2-2xy-2yz+2xz=0$$ is equivalent to
$$(x-y+z)^2=0 \Leftrightarrow x-y+z=0 $$
As for the addition, if $(x,y,z)\in L$ and $(x',y',z')\in L$, then
$$(x+x')-(y+y')+(z+z')=(x-y+z)+(x'-y'+z')=0 $$
so $(x+x',y+y',z+z')\in L$ as well.

Comment: Much thanks Bjorn!

Comment: if you would also be kind and give maybe a tip to a similar problem but with the equation $x^2-y^2-z^2 +2xy = 0$

Comment: That wouldn't be a subspace.

Comment: I took two elements and I am trying to show that their addition is in the subspace. But I am getting at the end $0+0 + (x_1 . x_2) -(y_1 . y_2) -(z_1 .z_2) + (x_1 . y_2)+(x_2 . y_1) = 0 $ How can I give a logical justification that it is not a subspace at this point?

Comment: If something isn't true, then you don't have to prove anything. You can just give a counterexample. In this case, two vectors which are in the set, but their sum isn't. Try with small numbers.

Comment: Solved it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Good, rank one, it really  is just the single squared term

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$